How did Letty and Cipher go from attacking each other to bonding?
As a result of Cipher’s actions, smoke was released on the
other side of the glass, causing the staff to suffocate from the gas.
This allowed her to unlock herself and Letty from their separate
examination beds:

Letty: How much time do we have?
Cipher: I'd say about four minutes.
Letty: It'll have to do.

Then, Letty tried to attack Cipher, but they later became companions and
escaped from the facility together.
How did Letty and Cipher go from attacking each other to bonding?

It's the standard trope of Rivals Team up, a sub trope of Frenemy, leaning on Defeat means friendship, which is a big standard for the fast and furious franchise.
(Standard tvtrope warning).
After letting go some steam with a good old beating, the hero and the rival come to the realisation the only way for them to get out of this situation is to team up, despite their differences.
